# How can I write WPF Rich textbox content to a word document?

Tags: wpf, ms-word

I want to write into a word document using DocX library for c# ms word document creating. How can I convert paragraphs to office word document paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

You have to grab each nodes of the `FlowDocument`, and then you'll end up with converting its content to the corresponding paragraph like `InsertAfter` method of the `DocX` library.

I tried using `DocX` but it wasn't easy to convert it from WPF to Word. We ended up using `RTF` to `Word` so that it layouts properly without having to deal with the layout of what it actually looks like in WPF and in Word

Sample

```
Table currentTable = CreateDocXTable(table.Columns.Count, table.RowGroups[0].Rows.Count);
if(block is Section)
{
 var editableSection = block as Section;
 var content = new TextRange(editableSection.ContentStart, editableSection.ContentEnd);
 currentTable.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Paragraphs[0].InsertText(content.Text);
}
```